# Android - Authenticating using Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: java, android, wif, windows-identity

We have a RESTful web service which uses WIF (Windows Identity Doundation) - STS , Token based authentication. And I would like to use it within a native android app.

could you guide me on where should I look to start from ?! 
any thing from a ready Library to a small Post which I can get an idea from is appreciated